# C# Form drag (not drop) file onClick

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface

I want that when you activate the onclick event of an element it gives me a file attached to my mouse like when you use the drag And Drop function.

I dont want to drop a file, i want to drag it from the form, there is some way to do this?

Edit:
I have made some progress... this is my code now for the onclick event:

```
    private void DragArchivo(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoDragDrop(File.Create(ruta), DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

I have an absolute root named ruta that point to a c# script:

```
C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\GitHub\\blabla\\blablaCommand.cs
```

This already works for dragging things like strings but i cant do it work whit files.

By the way, the objetive is to grab files from my program and drop them into visual studio to work whit it:[image]

Comment: we need more information about your form, are there files displayed? if so how? what information is behind the displaying control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem in the future here is a very cool person that has found the solution:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/576279/DragplusfileplusOUTplusofplusapplication

The code that i have finaly used is:

```
DataObject dragObject = new System.Windows.Forms.DataObject();
StringCollection filePaths = new StringCollection();
filePaths.Add(ruta);
dragObject.SetFileDropList(filePaths);
DoDragDrop(dragObject, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
```